# Updating production ArcSDE database from staging?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

We have development, staging and production instances of the same ArcSDE database, similar to [this ancient thread from the ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=2&f=59&t=185705).

Our development to staging deployment employs lots of schema changes with exclusive locks that involve dropping tables and recreating them. Our schema itself is pretty fluid as we are always adding new data to it.

Our staging database is an exact copy of what we want our production database to be.

How do I deploy our staging ArcSDE instance to production while minimizing or eliminating downtime?

We use SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use FME Workbench via the ArcGIS Data Interoperability Extension, which comes with our ESRI Enterprise License Agreement.

Using FME gives us the ability to:

- Promote from Dev to QA to Prod instances of ArcGIS
- Ensure Field names and Field Types are consistent between environments
- Provide an accessible tool for our non-GIS-using DBA to run an ETL to our production environment by embedding an FME tool into a Model Builder model
- Translate between SDE features classes and Native SQL Spatial
- Incorporate FME ETL processes into Python Scripts for automation

When we originally spoke to ArcGIS tech support regarding this same issue, we were told to 'copy and paste' between SDE geodatabases. This was not the workflow we wanted...